# How to change the text color of a list view item using radio buttons?

Tags: android

I have been trying to find a way for changing text color of a specific list view item using radio buttons, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help?

Comment: please show something what you have tried ?

Comment: If you have define bean for listview item then take a variable color and set default color. When you click on radio button change the color and notify adapter.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: please share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Adapter and ViewHolder for ListView items? 
If so, just write changing color code in your adapter. For example:

```
private static class ItemHolder {
    TextView name;
}
```

In adapter:

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CompanyDomain> {

private ArrayList<CompanyDomain> companies;

public CompanyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<CompanyDomain> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.companies = items;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemHolder itemHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_list_row, null);
        itemHolder = new ItemHolder();
        itemHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.companyNameTitle);
    }
    else {
        itemHolder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // condition here
    if (have to change color) {
        itemHolder.name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

But now, It is better to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with its [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)